# What is causing my HTML table cell to be smaller than the other?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I’m working on a website that displays current NBA game scores.
I’m having a tiny issue where I realized that my scores are displaying in different width table cells. How do I make them equal width?

Here’s what it currently looks like (cell at red arrow has longer width than cell at blue arrow):

[image: A screenshot of the issue shows that one table cell is wider than the other within the same table row. The wider cell is marked with a red arrow. The narrower table cell is marked with a blue arrow.]

Here’s the code:

```js
if (status == "Scheduled") {
  data += `<tr>
    <td class = "left" rowspan="2">${item.team1} <img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
    <td>${time}</td>
    <td>EST</td>
    <td class="right" rowspan="2"><img src=${item.team2Img}> ${item.team2}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="period" colspan="2"><img src = images/clock.png></td>
    </tr>`;
}
else if (status == 'Finished') {
  data += `<tr>
    <td class="left" rowspan="2"> ${item.team1} <img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
    <td> ${item.score1} </td>
    <td> ${item.score2} </td>
    <td class="right" rowspan="2"> <img src=${item.team2Img}>  ${item.team2}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td class="period" colspan="2">Final</td>
    </tr>`;
}
else {
  data += `<tr>
    <td class="left" rowspan="2"> ${item.team1} <img src=${item.team1Img}></td>
    <td> ${item.score1} </td>
    <td> ${item.score2} </td>
    <td class="right" rowspan="2"> <img src=${item.team2Img}>  ${item.team2}</td>
    </tr>`

  switch (period) {
    case "1":
      data += `<tr>
        <td class="period" colspan="2">${period}ST QTR</td>
        </tr>`;
        
      break;
    case "2":
      data += `<tr>
        <td class="period" colspan="2">${period}ND QTR</td>
        </tr>`;
        
      break;
    case "3":
      data += `<tr>
        <td class="period" colspan="2">${period}RD QTR</td>
        </tr>`;
        
      break;
    case "4":
      data += `<tr>
        <td class="period" colspan="2">${period}TH QTR</td>
        </tr>`;
  }
}
```

```css
.scores-screen {
  width: 700px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.11);
  backdrop-filter: saturate(300%) blur(100px);
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}

table {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  padding: 8px;
}

td {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="left" style="width:40%; ">Home</th>
      <th style="width:10%;" colspan="2">Score</th>
      <th class="right" style="width:40%;">Away</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tableData">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Unless you explicitly impose width constraints, a table cell expands so that its contents fit. The character "4" is fatter than the character "1", for example.

Comment: Right, but I'm not sure how to add constraints solely for the score tds

Comment: Consider editing your question and ensuring that the snippet shows the problem; provide a [mre] in an [edit] (focus on _minimal_ — think: Why do we need all these CSS colors if it’s just about the width? Why do we need to see several rows and all these images if it’s just about two table cells?). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. What do the applied CSS rules and the box model reveal?

Comment: Well I don't know how you want the scores to look, but it might work if you use just one `<td>` for both scores, and then space them apart and let the browser center that content in the "double" cell.

Comment: What is the widest content in the left table cells and what is the widest content in the right table cells? If the widths of these differ, so will the widths of both the columns.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's definitely the easy way out of this, was hoping there would be a more correct programming way to do it, thanks!